# Trouble with syntax with a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database for a sporting goods store and am attempting to create a table for the equipment. There is a syntax error with this code and I can not figure out what the problem is.

```
CREATE TABLE Equipment 
(
    EquipmentID Int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EquipmentName NChar(50) NOT NULL,
    Sport NChar(15) NULL,
    Manufacturer NChar(50) NULL,
    Price smallmoney NOT NULL,
    Quantity int NOT NULL,

    /*Sport must be one of the following*/
    CONSTRAINT SportCheck
        CHECK (Sport IN ('Baseball', 'Football', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 
'Soccer'))

   CONSTRAINT ValidQuantity CHECK (Quantity >= 0),
);
```

Comment: _always_ post the actual error. It's like saying "my car doesn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma before `CONSTRAINT ValidQuantity`

```
CREATE TABLE Equipment (
EquipmentID Int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EquipmentName NChar(50) NOT NULL,
Sport NChar(15) NULL,
Manufacturer NChar(50) NULL,
Price smallmoney NOT NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL,

/*Sport must be one of the following*/
CONSTRAINT SportCheck
Check (Sport IN ('Baseball', 'Football', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 
'Soccer')),

CONSTRAINT ValidQuantity
Check (Quantity >= 0),
);
```

Comment: Ya I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!